# C# commands explanation

Tags: c#

I have 2 files
First one:

```
public class Hello{ 
  public void hello(){
      System.Console.WriteLine("Hello!Hello!");
  }
}
```

Second one:

```
class App {
   public static void Main() { 
       Hello h = new Hello(); h.hello();
   }
}
```

I need to know what means and do each of the following lines

```
1 >sn -k hello.keys
2 >csc /t:library /keyfile:hello.keys hello.cs
3 >csc /t:exe /reference:hello.dll app.cs
4 > app
5 >csc /t:library /keyfile:hello.keys hello.cs
6 >app
7 >sn -k hello.keys
8 >csc /t:library /keyfile:hello.keys hello.cs
9 > app
10 >csc /t:library  hello.cs
11 >app
```

specially that "app" line!
Thank you for your help

Comment: Did you check the documentation?

Comment: Yes, I did check the documentation, some of it, but it's saying something like
"/target:library Build a library (Short form: /t:library)" and I need more details on all the commands.
If you know a better documentation please let me know!
And inside the doc I can't find what the "app" line does.

Comment: I don't even understand what the question is

Comment: @AlexS: I'd certainly find that clearer if that's what it means. I assumed the OP was posting a command per line. :)

Comment: @AlexS: having said that I'm looking at the documentation and still can't see what the app bit does...

Comment: I need to know what each line do

Comment: Are you trying to compile this from the command line?  'sn -k' creates a key, for example.  And 'csc' is used to compile your code to a `.dll`.

Comment: Correction, app is the name of the executable after csc command "csc /t:exe /reference:hello.dll app.cs"

Comment: @AlexS: Yeah, I worked that out for myself too and have now answered accordingly. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
csc /t:library File.cs // Compiles File.cs producing File.dll
```

[List of compiler (csc) options](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/6ds95cz0.aspx)

```
sn -k outfile //Generates a new key pair and writes it to the specified file.
```

[Overview of Strong Name Tool (sn.exe)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k5b5tt23%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

"app" is the name of the program after making it an executable in the line

```
csc /t:exe /reference:hello.dll app.cs
```

Answer (score 3):

There are three commands being run here:

- sn - used to create keys for strong naming (not used this much so
  can't say much more)
- csc - C# compiler (hence csc). This is used to compile source code into either DLLs (/t:library) or executable (/t:exe)
- app - this is the program that you have just created.

I'm not sure where you got these from but it looks like it is probably done with edits to source files between various stages. There would certainly be no point in just running those all in one go.

Anyway, that is the nutshell of what the commands are doing.